# Send mail using SMTP from multiple computers using just an ubuntu server?

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I have multiple computers in my LAN and I have one dedicated server online. I would like each of these computers to connect via SMTP to the dedicated server and be able to send an email out to me.

Problem is I don't really know where to start, for previous work on my dedicated server I installed mail-stack-delivery (Postfix + Dovecot) This works fine for sending mail from the server. But I am unable to connect remotely to it.

What I want is to be able to connect to smtp.dedicatedserver.com, Port 25, Authenticate using some credentials, Send email with Sender/Name headers.

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 1):

While it is unsure what exactly you want to do, I can suggest this article as a good start for completely setting up IMAP/SMTP, then, setting up mail client on other hosts should be piece of cake: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin